# Android kernel cross-compilation (ARM) on Mac

Tags: android, kernel, cross-compiling

What is the path to the ARM cross-compiler in the present distribution of the Android SDK? I am on Mac El Capitan. (I have read many different things all around and I'm a bit confused on how to declare the CROSS_COMPILE variable for compiling the kernel.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I am now able to answer my own question.

First, the cross-compiler is *not* part of the SDK, but of the NDK (Native Development Kit). So the first thing to do is fetching (installing) the NDK. I did this easily from Android Studio (which I use just to manage packages).

Second, the toolchain (the stack of tools used to build up a binary) is *not* there in the NDK directory tree: it has to be *extracted*. (It is not clear to me yet what this technically means - comments are welcome - what I understand is that the toolchain has to be "created".) To this aim, there is a Python script in the NDK directory tree, namely:

```
ndk-bundle/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py
```

Since I am interested in compiling for an ARM architecture, I invoked this by:

```
./make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch arm --install-dir <desired toolchain location>
```

At this point, a toolchain is extracted to the `<desired toolchain location>`, and inside there a cross-compiler may be found.